# array visualization in c with function

Tags: arrays, c, function, visualization, diagram

does someone know how I could potray an array like {5, 0, 2, 6} for example, like in the following picture, through a function in c?

[image]

I'm new to C, so I could really use some help here :)

This is all I have for now:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Diagram(int i, int x, int y, int v[])
{
    printf("y+\n");

    for(i = 0; i <= y; i++){
        printf(" |\n");
    }
    printf(" ");
    for(i = 0; i <= x; i++){
        printf("+---");
    }
    printf("+x");

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    int y = 10;
    int x = 5;
    int v[4] = {5, 0, 2, 6};

    Diagram(i, 5, 10, v);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My suggestion - do not print it right away. First create 2D array representing your "display". Then "draw" on it in-memory. After drawn, flush it to the screen row by row.

Comment: @TedLyngmo my bad, I meant to put v[4].

Comment: @Barmar Having an "API" to "draw" in arbitrary point of the display without worrying what to draw first definitely simplifies things by abstracting them out. This was a general suggestion.

Comment: Why aren't you using the `x` and `y` variables when calling `Diagram()`?

Comment: @YakovGalka Oops, didn't notice that there were parameters for the diagram size.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I edited it, thank you.

Comment: @EugeneSh. What do you mean exactly by creating the 2D array first?

Comment: @user17667602: see my answer for how to "create a 2D array first".

Answer (score 1):

As @Eugene said in the comments, the simplest way to tackle this is to create a temporary array, 'draw' into that array, and then print it onto the screen. For example:

```
void Diagram(int w, int h, int v[]) {
    char a[h][w+1];

    // initialize with blank lines
    for(int y = 0; y < h; ++y) {
        memset(a[y], ' ', w);
        a[y][w] = 0;
    }

    // draw the bars
    for(int x = 0; x < w; ++x)
        for(int y = 0; y < v[x] && y < h; ++y)
            a[y][x] = '|';

    // print the array onto the screen (in reverse order)
    for(int y = h; y --> 0; )
        puts(a[y]);
}

int main() {
    int v[4] = {5, 0, 2, 6};
    Diagram(4, 10, v);
}
```

This prints:

```
    
    
    
    
   |
|  |
|  |
|  |
| ||
| ||
```

I'll leave it for you as an exercise to draw the axes and increase the spacing between the bars. You'll need to increase the size of the array for that (be careful with the math).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest changing the arguments to `Diagram` slightly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Diagram(int graph_height, int v[], size_t cols) {
   // graph_height  the height you want the graph to be
   // v[]           the values
   // cols          number of columns in v
}
```

And you'd call it like so:

```
int main() {
    int graph_height = 10;

    int v[] = {8, 5, 0, 2, 6};

    Diagram(graph_height, v, sizeof v / sizeof *v);
}
```

Now, inside `Diagram`:

- First loop through all values in `v[]` and find the maximum value. This will be used later to scale the graph.
- Let `h` loop from `graph_height` to `1` (inclusive).

  - Let `col` loop from `0` to `cols - 1` (inclusive)

    - Is `graph_height * v[col] / max >= h` then print `!`, otherwise print  .
    - Print three spaces
  - Print a newline
- Finish by printing the `+---+` line.

Looking closer at `graph_height * v[col] / max >= h`:

- In `graph_height * v[col] / max` the result will be `graph_height` when `v[col] == max`. The smaller values will be scaled accordingly. If one value is `max / 2` it'll scale to become `graph_height / 2`. If the result is `>= h` the `!` should be printed, otherwise  .